# How can i get only one row data when the data is in a list?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.settingList = data;
```

Below are the output of data.

```
0: {id: 5, accountId: 8, name: "Support Email", value: "haozii_94@hotmail.com"}

1: {accountId: 8, name: "Domain Name"}

2: {accountId: 8, name: "Self Registration"}

3: {accountId: 8, name: "SMS Sender Id"}

4: {id: 8, accountId: 8, name: "Ticket System", value: "ajsdasd"}
```

length: 5
**proto**: Array(0)

How do i do so that i can put the data of `"Ticket system"` to a new scope?

Comment: $scope.yourvariable = data[4] , this is in your case since index of 'ticket system' is 4

Comment: Is your `data` object is an array or map ?